# @font-face: Why does this single font letter look different on Windows?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, fonts, font-face, webfonts

I've created a webfont set using fontsquirrel.com for a font called [InterFace by Dalton Maag](https://www.daltonmaag.com/library/interface). However the lowercase letter **s** looks different and slightly larger than all the other letters. This happens on Windows and on multiple browsers (tested on Chrome 53, Safari 5.1, Internet Explorer 11, Firefox 49) .

[image: larger letter S on windows]
(notice the lowercase S letters on Jessica and Clements)

The issue goes away if you zoom the browser to make the fonts larger:
[image]

But this doesn't happen on Ubuntu (chrome and firefox)

[image: does not happen on Ubuntu]

Is this an issue with Windows font rendering? Or could this be a "font hinting" issue? How can I fix this?

Comment: Some fonts just don't work at some sizes, but this also depends on your screen size and resolution too. The S in animals looks fine, so try a slightly different size.

Comment: @MatthewWilcoxson but it's working on Ubuntu though. I'm trying to find out why it works on Ubuntu, and if I can do anything to make it work **at that size** on Windows too. Also the font size was specified by the designer :( Thank you for the suggestion though.

Comment: I was assuming Ubuntu was on a different screen or resolution. Have you tried it in windows on different computers?

Comment: @MatthewWilcoxson yeah, all windows machines produce the same result. The Ubuntu is a VM on the same Windows machine the screenshots were taken on. Same resolution, same monitor etc.

Answer (score 1):

This was to do with "X-Height Snapping" on the TrueType (TT) hinting options. I had to download TTFAutoHint and manually adjust the configurations and hint the font file myself before generating derivatives through fontsquirrel.com leaving the TT hinting options as "Keep existing", instead of letting fontsquirrel handle the hinting (either using fontsquirrel hinting or ttfautohint hinting)

I had to set "X-Height Snapping Exceptions" to `-20` so that it doesn't use "snapping" on sizes less than 20ppem. This produced a correct height letter `s` at small font sizes. Here's my config:
[image: ttfautohint config]

The difference was clearly visible on the windows font preview when you don't set X-Height Snapping Exception:

[image]

And when you do set it to `-20`:

[image]

(Above are previews at 12pt)